# python multi threading communication

Tags: python, multithreading

I use a thread pool and and I submit some tasks to be proccessed.

Sometimes a server that I ping or my internet connection could be down. This can be determined by any of the running threads.

In that case I would like the thread that detected the error to notify the others to pause 
their execution until the error is fixed.

Do you know how is this possible?

I add to the above. The ideal solution would be :
when a threads detects the program to send a message to all other threads to wait.
Also it should notify an external server and after receiving that everything is ok from the 
server to send again a signal to the other threads to continue the work.

Comment: If any thread can detect this problem, then why not simply have each thread suspend itself until the network comes back?

Comment: Correct. Not thought about it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it using threading.Event

I just have an event

```
event = Event()
```

and I use the

```
event.wait()
```

In the beggining I

```
event.set()
```

when a thread detects an error it

```
event.clear()
```

and the threads are waiting until

```
event.set()
```

This seems to work